# How to change the default path gnuplot searches when changing terminal type?

Tags: gnuplot, x11

I am a user of a HPC system. I now would like to install a new version of gnuplot under my directory `/home/username`. I succeeded in installing, but now the default terminal type is `qt`. I now want to change it to `x11`. The command `set terminal x11` is not working, the error messages are:

> Expected X11 driver:
>   /home/app/gnuplot-5.0.6/libexec/gnuplot/5.0/gnuplot_x11 Exec failed: No
>   such file or directory See 'help x11' for more details

This is weird as I installed the gnuplot in

> /home/**username**/app/gnuplot-5.0.6/

and there is a `gnuplot_x11` in

> /home/**username**/app/gnuplot-5.0.6/libexec/gnuplot/5.0/gnuplot_x11

Is there a way to tell gnuplot that it searches in the wrong path? And is there a way to set the x11 terminal as the default one?

Thank you very much!

---

**Update:**

I can set `--with-qt=no`, now the default becomes `wxt`. Now I can use `set terminal x11`:

```
gnuplot> set terminal x11
Terminal type set to 'x11'
Options are ' nopersist enhanced'
```

I am not quite understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the directory in which gnuplot looks for the gnuplot_x11 driver by setting the `GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR` environment variable. From `help x11`:

> The gnuplot outboard driver, gnuplot_x11, is searched in a default
>   place  chosen when the program is compiled.  You can override that by
>   defining  the environment variable GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR to point to a
>   different  location.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not aware of it because `help x11` is not working on my machine yesterday. By the way, when and where should I put the environment variable GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR?

Comment: You can run `export GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIR=/home/username/app/gnuplot-5.0.6/libexec/gnuplot/5.0/` in the shell from which you execute gnuplot.