# Changing gnuplot x11 output defaults

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot over ssh (-X) and due to different screen resolution issues, my x11 output window has minuscule fonts. I want to access the `.Xdefaults` file as mentioned in documentation but cannot locate it. This question [GNUPLOT_DRIVER_DIRECTORY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44332674/how-to-change-the-default-path-gnuplot-searches-when-changing-terminal-type) pointed towards some solution but I don't want to input it every time. Can someone help me find a permanent fix for font sizes?

Comment: .Xdefaults is normally in your $HOME : $> cat ~/.Xdefaults # or create it

Comment: I created it and tried putting: set term x11 font "arial,15" on both the local and remote machines. It didn't work. Is there a specific format that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

What is your default terminal ? I think it shoulds be xterm, to have x11 as defaults.

```
shell> echo $TERM
```

What is yout default gnuplot terminal display ?

```
gnuplot> show term
```

Instruction in ~/.Xdefaults have a special syntax (some example in linuxcertif.com/man/1/gnuplot/ ). But i think that's not what you want to do. This is more for 'fine tuning'. And i think it will only be effective if your default terminal is allready x11.

> ```
> gnuplot*pointsize: 2
> gnuplot*background: white
> gnuplot*textColor: black
> ```

Anyway, it is better to use gnuplot with a text file : ***file.gp*** where you put your commands. Then just put in the beginning of your file :

> set term x11 font "arial,15"

And execute your file with :

> shell> gnuplot file.gp -

do not forget the 'dash' '-' at the end of the command, so that you can continue to put command in the gnuplot prompt to debug additional command.

Comment: My default terminal is xterm-256color for both remote and local machines. Gnuplot output windows is x11 for remote and qt for local. Adding these lines: gnuplot*pointsize... don't bring out any changes. I am aware of the .gp file but I am avoiding it because I want to change the default. I don't want to plot with a file for every little plot I want to have a quick look at.